# Mongoose - how to update an object array element based upon a key?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a key value pair in an object... located in an array.. in a database.

Posts is an array of objects. Each Object has an postId. I am trying to search through the array for the object that matches a postId. Once I find the right post, I want to be able to update other values in that object.

Kind of lost for a bit now... Thanks for your help!

```
router.put('/posts/:id',   (req, res) => {
    quoteGenerator.find({'posts': {$elemMatch: {postId: req.params.id}}}).then(gen => res.json(gen))
})
```

Comment: You can use the [positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html) to update an array element (which is a sub-document) based upon a condition.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I just about got it. It is updating the value I want it to update - BUT - when it updates the value, it adds a whole new object to the element thats updating.  Example : I am updating "approved": null --- then it updates it to "approved": { "approved": true }. I just need to figure out how to get rid of the second object and just update the value. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Glad I can learn about the $ operator.

Comment: Got it! Thanks again - Super easy!